# Aforge Canny Edge Detection and how i get the pixel value

Tags: aforge

Does canny edge detection only work with 8bppIndexed?
i want to get the value at a given pixel ex. (x,y). How can i do it

thanks

Comment: Is it a System.Drawing.Bitmap which stores your image data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it only works with 8bpp indexed images. See [here](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/e08cae30-7a37-db9f-cede-05cf6521343f.htm).

> The filter accepts 8 bpp grayscale images for processing.

You may want to keep the original around and pass a grayscale copy to the filter. This way you can retrieve the filtered value based on original location, or original value based on filtered location.